# Blinking LED with a PIC16F877 - Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic

This is my first attempt at programming in assembly and I can't figure out what is the wrong with this below code because it doesn't work properly.

```
include "P16F877.INC"

STATUS  equ 03h
TRISB   equ 86h
PORTB   equ 06h
COUNT1  equ 20h
COUNT2  equ 21h


        bsf     STATUS,5
        bcf     TRISB,0
        bcf     STATUS,5

Start   bsf     PORTB,0

Loop1   decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1
        decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1

        bcf     PORTB,0

Loop2   decfsz  COUNT2,1
        goto    Loop2
        decfsz  COUNT2,1
        goto    Loop2

        goto    Start


end
```

Comment: *it doesn't work properly* is not a useful problem description. How **specifically** does it not *work properly*? We can't see your screen or read your mind, and I don't happen to have that assembler or PIC available to attempt to run the code to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: I'm repeating a bit, but as a general advice, you need to give more details about your problem. "not working", is not really helpful. Does it assemble ? What does it do when you run it ? Someone might be able to help with little information, but the more you provide, the easiest and faster it will be for the volunteer helpers to find your problem. Also, it demotivate helpers if they have to make guesses.

Comment: for a program who is supposed to blink I would say: it does nothing (https://moodle.sapidoc.ms.sapientia.ro/pluginfile.php/3008/mod_resource/content/1/PIC16%20Instruction%20Set.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems are in double loops:

```
Loop1   decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1
        decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1
```

The first goto is skipped when COUNT1 is zero. But then you go to the second loop, which "reloads" the loop. You have an infinite loop here.

I don't know how `COUNT1` is initialized, but it doesn't matter. I would do that.

```
Loop1a  decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1a
        ; possibly reload COUNT1 with some value
Loop1b
        decfsz  COUNT1,1
        goto    Loop1b
```

of course, same thing for Loop2. I would even suggest that you do a subroutine that you call twice instead of copying/pasting.

very suprising assembler where conditions can skip the next instruction:

https://moodle.sapidoc.ms.sapientia.ro/pluginfile.php/3008/mod_resource/content/1/PIC16%20Instruction%20Set.pdf